# Meteor-Cordova: debug and hotpush when device is offline?

Tags: cordova, meteor

I'm developing a meteor (1.2) application, running on mobile (Cordova 5.2, Android 5.0).

I need to test the application in Chrome://inspect debugger while my computer is connected but my mobile device is offline (no Internet connection). Also I need hotpush to device of updated files.

However I can't do hotpush since on Chrome console I keep getting

```
 GET http://192.168.1.X:3000/sockjs/info? ... net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
```